# $.get() inside another $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i'm trying to send some data which i fetch throu a Jquery.get() to another jquery.get however it returns a "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation" error.
Here's the code i'm using:

```
$.get("../charactersheet",{keyid: keyid, charid: charid} ,function(xml){
    $.get("../getallskillfolders", {xmlcharactersheet: xml} , function(jsonallskillfolders){
        alert("Firing the getallSkillFolders servlet");
        console.log(jsonallskillfolders);
    });
});
```

Anyway around this and what is it caused by? I thought at first it might be because the first getter hadnt finished, but i was under the impression that the function should only be fired once it had done just that.

EDIT:

```
jquery.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
n.param.e @ jquery.min.js:4
Ac @ jquery.min.js:4
Ac @ jquery.min.js:4
Ac @ jquery.min.js:4
n.param @ jquery.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4
n.each.n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.min.js:4
(anonymous function) @ characterpage.js:183 = ($.get("../getallskillfolders", {xmlcharactersheet: xml} , function(jsonallskillfolders){
n.Callbacks.j @ jquery.min.js:2
n.Callbacks.k.fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2
x @ jquery.min.js:4
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send.b @ jquery.min.js:4
```

Comment: In which line did you get the error: Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation?

Comment: Do you really want to pass an xml document as a url parameter in a 'GET' request ? You may run into problems regarding the length of the url, try 'POST' instead.

Comment: Ah that's right completely forgot about the limit to the 'GET' request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks to me like you're trying to pass an XML document into the second `get`. If what the server returns for the first `get` is identified as XML, jQuery will parse it for you into an XML document and pass you that as the argument to the success function.

If you don't want it to do that, you can override that behavior by telling jQuery the response is `"text"` (the response data type is the [last argument](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jQuery-get-url-data-success-dataType) to `$.get`)):

```
$.get("../charactersheet",{keyid: keyid, charid: charid} ,function(xml){
    $.get("../getallskillfolders", {xmlcharactersheet: xml} , function(jsonallskillfolders){
        alert("Firing the getallSkillFolders servlet");
        console.log(jsonallskillfolders);
    });
}, "text");
// ^^^^^^
```

---

Or here's the `$.ajax` version (was part of my first answer, I'd never noticed that `$.get` had a fourth argument before):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../charactersheet",
    dataType: "text",
    data: {keyid: keyid, charid: charid},
    success: function(xml){
        $.get("../getallskillfolders", {xmlcharactersheet: xml} , function(jsonallskillfolders){
            alert("Firing the getallSkillFolders servlet");
            console.log(jsonallskillfolders);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Dont mind that it's a XML. Dont have alot experience with neither JSON nor XML.

Comment: That one worked like a charm. Thou i cant say i understand why.

Comment: It works when the $.ajax dataType: "text" but not as xml, anyone knows why?

Comment: @Kyathab: Because a parsed XML document isn't text, it's...a parsed XML document.